# Need Advice for a multiplayer game server configuration

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, socket.io, multiplayer

*I'll try to be as clear as possible, but english is notmy native language ;)*

What I want to do is to create a "join this game" interface. This will consists of different pages :

1. The "Connect Page" : if a user is not logged-in, he'llbe redirected here.
2. The "General Page" : the players can join created games or can create his own game room.
3. The "Waiting Room" : when a player join or create a game, he goes to this waiting room.
4. The "In Game Page" : when the creator of the game thinks there's enough players, he launches the game and all those players are send in the game.

My problem here, is that I don't know if I should create a physical different page for each; or just have a single page and .html() everything.

For the moment, I have managed to create a secured connection and everything work fine. Exept that each time i change page, the session is destroy and I lose every datas.

Here is my rep for code: https://github.com/Babas/croa

Comment: StackOverflow is not for user's Opinion

Answer (score 0):

Babas, I recommend you investigate angular and maybe the mean.js stack.  Angular will provide you separate views necessary to compartmentalize your view logic without losing your socket.io connetion.  The MEAN stack will give you a common project structure for the server and client-side pieces.

https://angularjs.org/

http://meanjs.org/

Comment: I didn't think of AngularJS, but it seems like a great idea. I'll have a try !